# Calculate the average "radius" of a polygon in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, area, radius

I am trying to calculate the average radius of RF coverage propagations. Each propagation looks almost like a paint splatter for visual reference.

I want to calculate the average radius across all of these individual coverage polygons, but it needs to be scalable. My first thought was to generate a centroid for each coverage polygon, then (with a geoprocessing tool hopefully), draw lines from the centroid to the edge of the polygon, then get an average length of each line to represent the average radius. I am not sure how to go about doing this.

As a side note, if there is a simple mathematical formula I can use and avoid having to do any geoprocessing that would be ideal. My first though was to simply reverse engineer the typical formula for an area of a circle but I am not sure if that would hold any water in this scenario.

Comment: Create a point at the geometric center of your polygon.  Export the polygons vertices to points.  Generate a near table from the center to the points.  Calculate the average distance?  Repeat for polygon 2.  This could be done with iterators in Model Builder or via Python.

Comment: I believe this will work, however, how would I make sure that the near table only generates distances between the centroid of say, Polygon A to the vertices of only Polygon A. Repeat for every polygon in the dataset. I would only want the near relationship between the centroid of a polygon to the vertices of the same polgyon.

Comment: GIS tools respect selections so if you have your centroid selected, and the points that make up the polygon you will be fine.  Again, you can automate all that in Modelbuilder or with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate vertices of polygons and compute their coordinates (A). Calculate centroids of polygons and compute their coordinates (B). Join field B to A and compute field D by:

```
math.hypot( !POINT_X! - !POINT_X_1! , !POINT_Y! - !POINT_Y_1! )
```

[image]

You can summarize D by ORIG_FID as a case. Note I've used center of larges inscribed circle, not centroid that might very well sit outside of the polygon.

[image]